# What does class_methods do in concerns?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am reading some codes which use the concerns in Rails 4.

I read some articles to say, if we would like to include class methods
using module `ClassMethods`, but the code I read using something like:

```
class_methods do
  def **** 
  end
end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's just for convenience. `module ClassMethods` is pure Ruby, but `class_methods` is defined in `ActiveSupport::Concern` for convenience. If you look at a source code you'll find that `class_methods` does exactly the same thing

```
  # activesupport/lib/concern.rb
  def class_methods(&class_methods_module_definition)
    mod = const_defined?(:ClassMethods, false) ?
      const_get(:ClassMethods) :
      const_set(:ClassMethods, Module.new)

    mod.module_eval(&class_methods_module_definition)
  end
```

Comment: I don't think `module ClassMethods` is "pure ruby" exactly though -- nothing in the ruby language will automatically do something special with a sub-module called `ClassMethods`, that too is coming from `ActiveSupport::Concern`.

Comment: Yes, Ruby wont do anything with ClassMethods by itself, but it doesn't came from ActiveSupport. Maybe for historic reasons people use this module name, I don't know. But it's still pure Ruby. You can name this module as you want http://yehudakatz.com/2009/11/12/better-ruby-idioms/

Comment: You are mistaken, ActiveSupport::Concern will indeed do something special with a sub-module specifically called `ClassMethods`, it does what you'd expect with it. https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/d06e42518a4fdd1732f1d75a43c69071bcd79245/activesupport/lib/active_support/concern.rb#L119  and https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/d06e42518a4fdd1732f1d75a43c69071bcd79245/activesupport/lib/active_support/concern.rb#L135-L137

Comment: ActiveSupport::Concern just uses ClassMethods module name to do this. You can do the same thing without ActiveSupport in pure Ruby  https://gist.github.com/olegantonyan/73872d290f04e519e3c5

Comment: Of course you can. But if you name your sub-module `ClassMethods`, AS::Concern does it for you, and you don't need to implemented the `def self.included` with the `extend` yourself. For that matter, it's all "plain ruby", but you're right implementing what AS::Concern does with `ClassMethods` only takes one fairly simple line, I agree. While implementing what AS::Concern does with `class_methods do` takes four or five, more confusing, lines, it's true. But it's all just 'pure ruby' in the end, including what AS::Concern is doing.

Answer (score 73):

[`ActiveSupport::Concern`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html) provides syntactic sugar for common Ruby patterns for module mixins.

When you are using [modules as mixins](https://www.culttt.com/2015/07/08/working-with-mixins-in-ruby/) you can't just use `self` to declare class methods like you would from a class:

```
module Foo
  def self.bar
    "Hello World"
  end
 
  def instance_method
    "Hello World"
  end
end

class Baz
  include Foo
end
```

```
irb(main):010:0> Baz.bar
NoMethodError: undefined method `bar' for Baz:Class
    from (irb):10
irb(main):011:0> Foo.bar
=> "Hello World"
irb(main):012:0>
```

As you can see from the example that actually creates a module method - thats because `self` is the module. You can use extend instead:

```
module Foo
  def a_class_method
    "Hello World"
  end
end

class Bar
  extend Foo
end
```

```
irb(main):049:0> Bar.a_class_method
=> "Hello World"
```

But that does not let you declare instance methods in the module. Which is not really that useful.

So the solution is to create an inner module which is commonly named `ClassMethods` and extend the class when the module is included:

```
module Foo
  # this is a method thats called when you include the module in a class.
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend ClassMethods
  end

  def an_instance_method
  end
   
  # the name ClassMethods is just convention.
  module ClassMethods
    def a_class_method
      "Hello World"
    end
  end
end

class Bar
  include Foo
end
```

```
irb(main):071:0> Bar.a_class_method
=> "Hello World"
```

This boilerplate code is found in almost every Ruby gem/library.

By extending your module with `ActiveSupport::Concern` you can shorten this to just:

```
module Foo
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  class_methods do
    def a_class_method
      "Hello World"
    end
  end
end
```

Under the hood `ActiveSupport::Concern` creates a `ClassMethods` module and evaluates the block in the context of the module. Dig into [the source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/fc5dd0b85189811062c85520fd70de8389b55aeb/activesupport/lib/active_support/concern.rb#L136) if you curious about how it actually does this.

Comment: I'm surprised it's been 3 years since you've had someone make a comment here to thank you for your excellent answer to this question. Finally, someone that actually answers what we're all really wanting to know, from beginning to end, with tips and taps along the way. You are most certainly a good teacher. Thank you. It takes a lot of understanding to realise what exactly you need to impart on others. You got it man.

Comment: This is a great answer.

Answer (score 3):

`class_methods` is used to add class methods to the model used by the concern.

A typical module looks like this:

```
module M
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend ClassMethods
  end

  module ClassMethods
    ...
  end
end
```

By using `ActiveSupport::Concern` the above module could instead be written as:

```
require 'active_support/concern'

module M
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  class_methods do
    ...
  end
end
```

As [Oleg Antonyan pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33326341/462015), from the source code, we know that it's going to use `ClassMethods` module under the hood.

Reference: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html